# Python Dictionary Creation TypeError

Tags: python, debugging

What I want to do is to create a dictionary with two fields (uuid an path) and fill them with ubuntu command line outputs

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

Devices = []


def UUID():
    blkid = Popen(['sudo', 'blkid'], stdout=PIPE)
    sed = Popen(['sed', 's/^.*UUID="/UUID="/'], stdin=blkid.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    cut = Popen(['cut', '-d', '"', '-f', '2'], stdin=sed.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    end_of_pipe = cut.stdout
    Devices = [{'uuid': uuid, 'path': None} for uuid in end_of_pipe]
    return Devices


def Path(Devices):
    blkid = Popen(['sudo', 'blkid'], stdout=PIPE)
    cut = Popen(['cut', '-d', ':', '-f', '1'], stdin=blkid.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    end_of_pipe = cut.stdout
    for path in end_of_pipe:
        Devices['path'] = path
    return Devices

Devices = UUID()
Path(Devices)
print Devices
```

ERROR returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 24, in <module>
    Path(Devices)
  File "2.py", line 20, in Path
    Devices['path'] = path
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: What is confusing you about that error? Devices is a list, you can't index lists with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Devices` is a `list` of `dict` objects, not a `dict` object itself. You have to first figure out which index you want to access, and then access the object's `path` key. An example would be:

```
Device[0]['path'] = 'some/path'
```

In your case, **if** `end_of_pipe` holds paths in **the same order** as `Devices` you can do:

```
for path, device in zip(end_of_pipe, Devices):
    device['path'] = path
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is capable of parsing text. You don't need to use external tools such as *sed* and *cut* to do it.

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, Pipe

pattern = re.compile(r'^(?P<path>[^:]+).*UUID="(?P<uuid>[^"]+)')
devices = []
blkid = Popen(['sudo', 'blkid'], stdout=PIPE)
for line in f:
    match_object = re.match(pattern, line)
    if match_object:
        devices.append(match_object.groupdict())
```

At this point, *devices* will contain a list of dictionaries, each dictionary contains two keys: *path* and *uuid*. This solution also have another advantage: you only call `blkid` once.